# ASP.NET MVC 3 CMS supporting multi-tenancy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, razor, saas

I'm looking for a lightweight CMS solution that can be integrated into an existing ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) website.

The main problem i'm having is a requirement to be able to support multiple accounts in the same site within the same domain and the same DB.

So users can change their own views of their pages on my system.  It's pretty mush a SaaS site that the user (or users belonging to the same organisation) should be able to edit without impacting other users' views.

I haven't found anything out of the box and suspect my requirements may require a bespoke solution.

Would appreciate any advice/links to potential solutions.  I've looked at N2CMS, Orchard, Meek, Umbraco and MVCCMS and don't think any of those support this requirement - unless i've missed something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is interested i have settled on Orchard.  I'm achieving multi-tenancy by using a sub-domain per tenant.  I don't think i really understood how this was going to work when i asked the question, tenant per sub-domain seems like an obvious solution now :)